Which formula is faster in google sheets? How can I figure that out on my own?
=TRANSPOSE({VLOOKUP(C13,'range1'!C:E,3,0);XLOOKUP(C13,'range1'!C:C,'range1'!A:A)})
or
=QUERY(FILTER('range1'!A:E,'range1'!C:C=C13),"SELECT Col5, Col1")
These do the exact same thing for my purposes. These formulas will fill about 200 cells, and range 1 consists of 8500 rows and 19 columns. Which one is faster or more stable?
They visibly populate in around the same time. My thinking would be to use an app script to determine the ms required for each execution. How else could I go about figuring out the faster formula?
